# Capistrano Config symlink not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am doing Rails 4.1 deployment with Capistrano 2.

My script is working fine but in create_symlink task it crashes.

```
executing "rm -f /home/deployer/myawesomeproject/production/current;  ln -s /home/deployer/myawesomeproject/production/releases/20150511102623 /home/deployer/myawesomeproject/production/current; true"
```

The result I got is

```
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/deployer/myawesomeproject/production/current’
```

It working fine but started crashing all of sudden.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are the file permissions? Perhaps something got messed up there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825928/capistrano-deploy-symlink-fails